# Best practice when renewing memberships while changing from one type to another

Tags: civimember, contributions

we offer two types of memberships (reduced and regular) that vary on financial status of the member, ie. if a person is unemployed/student/retired they pay the reduced fee but if their financial situation changes they pay the regular one.
When renewing the membership and the type of the membership changes (from regular to reduced for example) should one renew the current membership and change in the new window membership type or just add a new membership with the current one?

If I change the type from renewal window I lose the info of the previous type (it/s visible in contribution tab) but if I add a new membership then there is a chance of having concurrent regular and reduced memberships?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I lose the info of the previous type (it/s visible in contribution tab)

If the loss of info is key issue you could try this [extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/contactmembershiplog) which lets you view the changes that occur when a member renews but up/downgrades their Memb Type